# Search for seller in Aliexpress

Tags: aliexpress

I would like to search for a particular seller in AliExpress. Looks I can do search only by items, but not sellers.

Is it possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Just to type the store name on a web search engine. Usually you can find the store pretty easily like this if you remember the store's name.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the store number, just put it at the end of this link:

https://www.aliexpress.com/store/#######

where ####### is the 6 or 7 digit store number

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best option is to check in your history, if you already visited his/her page